# Trying to add NixOS non packaged pytest-bdd to a shell.nix environment

Tags: python, python-3.x, nix, nixos

I\'d like to create a simple python project, and the nixos documentation
was helpul. So I have a *shell.nix* file with the following content:

```
with import <nixpkgs> {};

(
  python3.withPackages (ps: [ps.ipython ps.flask ps.pytest])
).env
```

Then I run *nix-shell* on the project folder and everything seems fine.

The problem I have is that I want to add *pytest-bdd* but it seems that
isn\'t packaged for NixOS, as *nix search pytest-bdd* doesn\'t return
any results.

So I try *behave* instead of *pytest-bdd* because it is already
packaged for NixOS, but unfortunately the *behave* binary isn\'t
available, while *ipython* and *flask* are. And the *behave*
documentation stats a binary should be available.

So I decided to try a different approach for *pytest-bdd* and I
followed the example on https://nixos.org/nixpkgs/manual/#python
(15.17.1.2.1. Packaging a library).

```
with import <nixpkgs> {};

(
  let
    my_pytestbdd = python37.pkgs.buildPythonPackage rec {
      pname = "pytest-bdd";
      version = "3.2.1";

      src = python37.pkgs.fetchPypi {
        inherit pname version;
        sha256 = "1ibyr40g3p6xbx1m59as3s9spyadz8wyc7zwqyzibphrw4pkvrqp";
      };

      doCheck = false;

      meta = {
        homepage = "https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-bdd/";
        description = "BDD library for the py.test runner";
      };
    };

  in python37.withPackages (ps: [ps.ipython ps.flask ps.pytest ps.glob2 my_pytestbdd])
).env
```

And I\'m stuck with this message:

```
Processing ./pytest_bdd-3.2.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting glob2 (from pytest-bdd==3.2.1)
  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement glob2 (from pytest-bdd==3.2.1) (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for glob2 (from pytest-bdd==3.2.1)
builder for '/nix/store/d94madfidxgn5r0k9kivfidn4p2cvyjk-python3.7-pytest-bdd-3.2.1.drv' failed with exit code 1
cannot build derivation '/nix/store/ypc7hpylzvmxx8lmk5cfg8jfhrfalzgn-python3-3.7.5-env.drv': 1 dependencies couldn't be built
error: build of '/nix/store/ypc7hpylzvmxx8lmk5cfg8jfhrfalzgn-python3-3.7.5-env.drv' failed
```

Answer (score 1):

### Solution

So after plenty of hours navigating documentation, I managed to get a
working solution that I\'d like to share to avoid people the same pain I
experienced.

This is my *shell.nix* file:

```
with import <nixpkgs> {};

(
  let
    my_pytestbdd = python37.pkgs.buildPythonPackage rec {
      pname = "pytest-bdd";
      version = "3.2.1";

      src = python37.pkgs.fetchPypi {
        inherit pname version;
    sha256 = "1ibyr40g3p6xbx1m59as3s9spyadz8wyc7zwqyzibphrw4pkvrqp";
      };

      buildInputs = [ python37.pkgs.glob2 python37.pkgs.parse python37.pkgs.six 
python37.pkgs.py python37.pkgs.parse-type python37.pkgs.Mako python37.pkgs.pytest ];

      doCheck = false;

      meta = {
        homepage = "https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-bdd/";
        description = "BDD library for the py.test runner";
      };
    };

  in python37.withPackages (ps: [ps.ipython ps.flask ps.pytest my_pytestbdd])
).env
```

And running *nix-shell* successfully created the environment.

Answer (score 1):

if you're happy to just use a `requirements.txt` file, you can bend nix to work the normal way with a virtualenv, see the default.nix below:

```
with import <nixpkgs> {};
with pkgs.python37Packages;

stdenv.mkDerivation {
  name = "impurePythonEnv1d";
  buildInputs = [
    taglib
    openssl
    git
    libxml2
    libzip
    python37Full
    python37Packages.virtualenv
    stdenv
    libffi
    zlib ];
  src = null;
  shellHook = ''
    unset http_proxy
    export GIT_SSL_CAINFO=/etc/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
    SOURCE_DATE_EPOCH=$(date +%s)
    virtualenv --no-setuptools venv
    source venv/bin/activate
    pip install jedi
    pip install ipython==5.2.0
    pip install pylint
    pip install flake8
    pip install -r requirements.txt
  '';
}
```

then create a `requirements.txt` and `nix-shell` it up

Comment: Thanks. this solution is interested for more complicated setups. Definitively I'll give it a shot.